# data-ng-show not working when trying to toggle menu in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am very new to angularjs and just learning. I have a question regarding **data-ng-show**
Here is my html markup and angularjs script:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="ShowHideController">
        <button data-ng-click="toggleMenu()">
            Toggle Menu</button>
        <ul data-ng-show="menuState" data-ng-repeat="cust in Customers">
            <li>{{ cust.name }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHideController($scope) {
            $scope.Customers = [
                { name: 'Customer1', age: 32 },
                { name: 'Customer2', age: 34 },
                { name: 'Customer3', age: 28}];
            $scope.menuState = false;
            $scope.toggleMenu = function () {
                $scope.menuState = !$scope.menuSate;
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

List is intially hidden and after clicking Toggle Menu button, it appears. But after this Toggle Menu button does not show/hide the list again, or in other words Toggle button functionality is all gone/doesn't work. I tried with **$scope.menuStart.show = !scope.menuStart.show**, but it doesn't seem to work as well. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled the variable!

```
$scope.menuState = !$scope.menuSate; //MISSING A "T" IN STATE
```

Should be:

```
$scope.menuState = !$scope.menuState;
```